# Incorrect result when finding probabilities of A and NOT B

Tags: probability, statistics

I’m studying for my stats midterm and am doing probability problems. The current problem provides values of

$P(A)=0.3$

$P(B)=0.4$

P($A\cap B$)=0.2

There were a few questions that I got right but I'm on stuck on this one. My goal is to find: P($A\cap \overline{B}$)

I started out by setting up the equation

$A\cap \overline{B}=P(A)*P(\overline{B}|A)$

In order to find $P(\overline{B}|A)$ I then said:

$P(\overline{B}|A)$ = $1-P(B|A)$. This logic lead me to

$P(B|A) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$

$=\frac{0.2}{0.3}$

$=0.666...$

Returning to $P(\overline{B}|A)$  I get

$P(\overline{B}|A) = 1-0.666...$

$=0.333...$

Then I finally solved for the desired probability

$P(A\cap \overline{B})=0.3*0.333...$

$=0.10$

But my textbook is telling me that the correct result is 0.15

Where am I going wrong in my process or calculations?

Comment: You’re correct but over complicated it. It’s just $P(A\cap B^c) = P(A)-P(A\cap B) = 0.3-0.2=0.1.$

Comment: Another way is $P(A)=P(A\cap(B\cup\bar B))=P(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap\bar B)\implies 0.3=0.2+P(A\cap\bar B)$

Comment: A Venn diagram might be helpful. It will reveal that $A$ is the disjoint union of $A\cap B$ and $A\cap\overline B$.

Comment: @Benjamin Wong Well that’s embarrassing. I think I actually saw that result during a prior search but doing so yielded the same 1.0 so I thought I was still screwing it up. Do you think it’s possible that the textbook answer key has it wrong then? I checked and I didn’t misread the question. It’s exactly as I posted it.